# cy.get() input using ng-model attibute?

Tags: angularjs, cypress

Lets say I've got the following form with two input elements.

```
Title:
<input type="text" ng-model="detail.message.title">
Description:
<input type="text" ng-model="detail.message.description">
```

To get Cypress.io to fill in the text input I should use code like

```
cy.get('<selector>').type('Here the data for the title')
```

The text input has no class, name or ID so I was wondering if it would be possible to select text input using the 'ng-model' attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attribute selector `input[ng-model="model name here"]`and see if it is working.

ex:

`cy.get('input[ng-model="detail.message.title"]').type('Here the data for the title')`

> Note: It is entirely based on your requirement but I feel this is not recommended, Instead you can add a class or ID and use respective selector, because if the attribute value changes in future then you have to change in Cypress as well.